# Convert values to negative on presence of string in another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a df where I want to convert the value in column a to a negative, if the string in column b is "negative".

consider the following:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, "postive"], [1, "negative"]]), columns=['a', 'b'])
print(df)

    a   b
0   1   postive
1   1   negative
```

I would like to convert the df to look like this:

```
    a   b
0   1   postive
1   -1  negative
```

This question is similar to one I found, however I couldn't see how to easily convert the answers of this question to apply for my own problem:
[Convert values to negative on the condition of values from another column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64796768/convert-values-to-negative-on-the-condition-of-values-from-another-column)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html):

```
# df['a'] = df['a'].astype(int)

df['a'] = df['a'].mask(df['b'].eq('negative'), -df['a'])
```

Or, if you are unsure whether the initial number if positive or already negative:

```
df['a'] = df['a'].mask(df['b'].eq('negative'), -df['a'].abs())
```

and if there is also a chance that positive values are incorrectly set as negative:

```
df['a'] = df['a'].abs().mask(df['b'].eq('negative'), -df['a'])
```

output:

```
    a         b
0   1   postive
1  -1  negative
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
import numpy as np
df['a'] = df['a'].astype(int).mul(np.where(df['b']=='postive', 1, -1))
print(df)
```

---

```
   a         b
0  1   postive
1 -1  negative
```